# Android ListView with Title

Tags: android, listview

I want to add a title bar in the list view.

I have added a text view inside the listview which can act as title:

Layout File :

```
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rounded"
       android:layout_marginRight="10px"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
       android:layout_marginTop="30px"
       android:layout_below="@id/linlaypay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >


     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/rectran"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >

     </ListView>
     </LinearLayout >
```

Here is the code used to add the title listview dynamically:

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rectran);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("header view");

    listView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

The problem is ,an emty text view isadded to the listview without the text "header view".
Why?Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can just add a view like this. The view being passed into listView needs to be inflated.

create a header.xml layout file with the text view in it with the text set.. and then run the code below.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would add a title to the `ActionBar`, assuming that your `ListView` is the whole `Activity`. If it isn't the whole `Activity` or it doesn't take up the whole screen, you could add the title to the layout rather than dynamically adding it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

Check out the Android Developers documentation on the `ActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

My activity holds 3 small listviews and I wanted to give title to each of the view by adding textview.

However the text in the Textview was not visible because the size of the text was too small.

setting the text size of the textview resolved the  issue.

Thanks !!